# Specify direction of the cursor on an indexeddb index in dartlang

Tags: dart, indexeddb

How do I specify the direction the cursor will take when iterating the found objects in an indexeddb objectstore in dart?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 28108 this works like this:

```
Future<String> getObject(int keyvalue, String storeName)=>
    db.transactionStore(storeName, "readonly")
      .objectStore(storeName)
      .index("frameId");
      .openCursor(key: keyvalue, direction: "prev", autoAdvance: true)
      .first
      .then((CursorWithValue cursor)=>cursor.value)
```

Allowed values for the direction are: "next", "nextunique", "prev" and "prevunique".

This answer was taken from https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2694